# Read & Store cookies created in WebView

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview

I have a Android Application which is basically uses WebView for all interaction..

How can i access (read) Cookies which are created in WebView (if someone logs in) and than store them somewhere, maybe in SharedPreferences, so that later i can use them.

For example.. on quitting the application .. i can say "Thank Mr.XYZ,do u really want to quit"

Here is my code...

```
package com.example.hellowebview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebView extends Activity {
WebView webview;

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(

    ));

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.mysite.com/mobile");
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Thank <<Name Cookie value from Webview >>>,do u really want to quit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Question modified ..plz chk now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with WebView cookies, you can use `CookieManager` which has some getter and setter methods for you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

Comment: You're using CookieSyncManager - this is different, and doesn't do what you want. You need to use CookieManager instead.

Comment: How do i know which webview is attached to the current CookieManager instance?